# rails: query with regualr expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I'm trying to implement a filtering drop-down search field in android. I'm using RESTful template and a rails api for my db. I have a model called skill. What I would like to be able to do is pass a string with a GET request and query a user's skills returning only the ones with a name containing the string.

I'd imagine it would look something like:

```
 def index
    search_string = params[:myString]
    @skills= curr_user.skills.where(skill_name: contains search_string)
    render json: @skills

  end
```

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: This will be very unpleasant.  The nearest thing you can do is a LIKE with % wildcards in the SQL, but SQL itself is not regex friendly for searches.  Even the like with wildcards should be avoided unless you are searching the beginning of a string.  Otherwise it's going to be super, super slow on large datasets even with an index.

Comment: Hmm, ok. Can you recommend a faster solution?

Comment: Consider breaking the strings into individual words and storing them in a words table.  If you do this you will need to create a join table to allow you to put the strings back together, but it will also allow you to search for individual words rather than a massively inefficient LIKE clause that tries to wildcard the entire string.

Comment: Which strings do u mean? The string being passed? The passed string would mostly be a single word or two. Like "xml" or "data processing"

Comment: I mean break the strings that represent the skill name into single words.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Rails `where` and `like`

```
def index
  search_string = params[:myString]
  @skills= curr_user.skills.where("skill name LIKE ?", "%#{search_string}%")
  render json: @skills
end
```